# Problem with gmapping.launch file

Tags: ros, navigation, clearpath, jackal, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

I am a newbie to ROS. Please bear with me.

I was following the tutorials by Clearpath Robotics for Navigation basics.
Here is the link: [ROS Navigation Basics](http://www.clearpathrobotics.com/guides/ros/ROS%20Navigation%20Basics.html)

Here, at the step where I have to launch the gmapping.launch file, I get the following error :

ERROR: cannot launch node of type [gmapping/slam_gmapping]: gmapping
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/sri/jackal_navigation/src
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/indigo/share
ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/indigo/stacks

I am not sure what this error means. Can anybody please help?

P.S. There is another question where the similar error was obtained [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/200677/problems-with-using-gmapping-cannot-launch-node/).
However, the answers there did not help me in resolving the issue.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225227/problem-with-gmapping.launch-file/) by [Srinidhi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25631/srinidhi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2016-01-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-01-28**:
are you sure `gmapping` is installed? Just run a `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-slam-gmapping` to install it.

It is also a bit odd, that you have `/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros` in your path. In which order did you source the workspaces and did you edit the `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` manually?

**Comment by [Srinidhi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25631/srinidhi/) on 2016-01-28**:
Thank you! I had installed gmapping by pulling it from github, but after installing thru aprt-get it's working fine. I sourced the workspaces as per the tutorial. I did not edit the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH.
I am not sure of /opt/ros/indigo/share/ros in my path. Is it gonna pose a problem in the future?

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-01-28**:
I'll just post as an answer, as it is solved now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Seems as if `gmapping` is not installed and/or not on your `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`.

Install via `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-slam-gmapping`.
If you want to build it from source, you need to put it in your ROS workspace (I'm guessing in `/home/sri/jackal_navigation/src` and build the workspace.

About your strange paths in the `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`:

Maybe try to build again with the following commands in a new terminal (make sure you don't source anything in the bashrc).

```
source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
cd /home/sri/jackal_navigation
catkin_make
source /home/sri/jackal_navigation/devel/setup.bash
echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
```

And check the output.
The output should be (approximately ;-) ):

1. `/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks`
2. `/home/sri/jackal_navigation/src:/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks`

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2